# JMeter how to send email through MS Exchange?

Tags: outlook, jmeter, smtp, exchange-server

For my machine, after logging in the windows system, the outlook logon automatically with Anonymous Authentication.

The outlook connects to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP, and connects using SSL only.
The principal name in the certificate is known when connecting to proxy servers.

```
Header:email.server.sample
```

The URL to connect to my proxy server for Exchange is known.

```
https://email.server.sample
```

"Negotiate Authentication" is used when connecting to the proxy server for Exchange.

Now, the question is, how can JMeter sends out the email with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box JMeter can only send emails via [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) protocol with [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) and/or receive emails using [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) and/or [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) protocols with [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler)

---

If you have to work with [Exchange protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd877045(v%3Dexchg.140)) you basically have 2 options:

1. [Send SOAP requests using HTTP Request sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
2. Use a wrapper library, i.e. [`ews-java-api`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler

Comment: Hi Dmitri! Can you please give an example how to use (send and maybe receive mail) the HTTP Request sampler for MS Exchange protocol? I've checked your recommended solution 1.) ( unfortunetelly 2.) is not an option for me), but it is still not clear. I need to emulate sending a mail from my Outlook 2010 and also checking the respone mail. Not sure of Jmeter is able to "catch" that mail. In my Outlook i only see exchange server details, so i need to make the whole exchange through that i guess.